# Why does this after delete trigger in phpmyadmin fail?

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have a table where among the various data I have 3 columns named as follows:

1. Casa
2. InizioPossesso
3. FinePossesso

Whenever a row in this table is deleted by the DELETE command:

1. the database engine checks if there is a row with the same value of "Casa" and "FinePossesso" = null.
2. If such a row does not exist then look for the row that has the same casa value as the deleted row with the highest FinePossesso date and set this value to NULL.

EXAMPLE:

```
ROW 1 - Casa: 1 - InizioPossesso: 10/03/2021 - Fine Possesso: Null -
ROW 2 - Casa: 1 - InizioPossesso: 05/01/2021 - Fine Possesso: 10/03/2021 -
ROW 3 - Casa: 1 - InizioPossesso: 30/09/2020 - Fine Possesso: 05/01/2021 -
ROW 4 - Casa: 2 - InizioPossesso: 05/07/2020 - Fine Possesso: Null -
ROW 5 - Casa: 2 - InizioPossesso: 02/02/2020 - Fine Possesso: 05/07/2020 -
```

If I delete row 1 the system must take row 2 and set null FinePossesso (because there is no other row with the same value of casa and FinePossesso = null and row 2 has the highest value of FinePossesso relative to the casa=1).

I wrote this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `casaVecchioProprietario` 
AFTER DELETE ON `casacittadino`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM casacittadino WHERE casa = old.casa AND dataFinePossesso is Null)
THEN
UPDATE casacittadino AS cc 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT casa, max(dataInizioPossesso) mdip FROM casacittadino WHERE casa = old.casa GROUP BY casa) cc1 ON cc.casa = cc1.casa AND cc.dataInizioPossesso = cc1.mdip SET dataFinePossesso = null;
END IF;
END
```

The problem is that when the event occurs it gives me this error:

**Can't update table 'casacittadino' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.**

How con I fix?

THANKS!!!!

Comment: That's an absolute restriction so you cannot use trigger. Consider deleting and updating via a procedure.

Comment: Front-end is written in php ... do you recommend me to do it via php? I would like to use a trigger to improve performance...